# Swift searchRecentTweets function expected parameter Set<Tweet.Field>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter, set

hello I am using swift on xcode 13.4.1 with Twift library for twitter
(https://github.com/daneden/Twift) trying to send a request to fetch tweets with
a query this is the code :

```
import UIKit
import Twift
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sentimentLabel: UILabel!

let twift = Twift(appOnlyBearerToken: myToken)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Task {
        let result =  try await **twift.searchRecentTweets**(query: "Apple",
        fields: Set<weet.Field>, 
        maxResults: 100).data
        for r in result{
          print(r.text)
           }
         }
      }
    }
```

i am having a problem on this line (fetching the tweets) :

```
 let result =  try await twift.searchRecentTweets(query: "Apple",fields: , 
 maxResults: 100).data
```

I need my tweets to return as english language only. the fields parameter is expecting  Set<Tweet.Field> , I don`t know how to accomplish that. this is what i found out via sources about the type [field declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNiXy.png)[field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RefGA.png)

My aim is to change the lang in the query field to english -"en"

please help

Comment: func searchRecentTweets(query: String, fields: Set<Tweet.Field> = [], expansions: [Tweet.Expansions] = [], endTime: Date? = nil, startTime: Date? = nil, maxResults: Int = 10, nextToken: String? = nil, sinceId: Tweet.ID? = nil, untilId: Tweet.ID? = nil) async throws -> TwitterAPIDataIncludesAndMeta<[Tweet], Tweet.Includes, Meta>
Parameters


fields 
Any additional fields to include on returned objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fields` parameter is a set of additional fields to be returned on the tweet objects. If you don't need any additional fields, you can supply an empty set `[]`.

To return only English language tweets, you need to modify the [query](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) you are sending to Twitter:

```
let result =  try await twift.searchRecentTweets(query: "Apple lang:en",fields:[] ,maxResults: 100).data
```